# Copy multiple files from a single source to different destinations, (recursively)

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy

I have 4 files in a single source folder (`c:\sandbox\image\`).

Files are as follows, `INSTALL1.SWM`, `INSTALL2.SWM`, `INSTALL3.SWM`, `INSTALL4.SWM`.

My destination structure is `c:\sandbox\extract\*\*\*`

I want to be able to copy them only if they exist in the destination folder(s). My challenge is the destination top folder is the same name all the time, however the sub folders names change so I end up with wildcards.

I have tried `xcopy` with the `/U`, and `/S`, parameters, but it's copying `0` files, so I think I'm missing something.

Here is what I was trying in my batch file, with no success.

```
xcopy c:\sandbox\image\*.SWM c:\sandbox\extract\ /U /S
```

Comment: Welcome.  Plase take the [tour], read [ask] and [mcve].  You should include the exact directory structure you have for your destinations.  Note that for 4 files, you could just write 4 copy commands and move on :)

Comment: made some edits to my question.  I'm not opposed to making 4 different commands for the source.  My challenge remains that the destinations are wildcards and xcopy doesn't seem to like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /ad /s/b "C:\sandbox\extract"') do for /L %%c in (1,1,4) do if exist "%%b\install%%c.swm" ECHO copy /y "c:\sandbox\image\install%%c.swm" "%%b\install%%c.swm"
```

Should `echo` the required `copy` commands. Remove the `echo` keyword to actually execute the `copy`s. Append `>nul` to suppress the `1 file(s) copied` message.

Untested, and assuming the requirement is to copy `install?.swm` over any existing versions in the subtree with root `"C:\sandbox\extract"`

[again untested - in response to comments]

```
for /f "delims=" %%b in ('dir /ad /s/b "C:\sandbox\extract"') do for %%c in ("" 2 3 4) do if exist "%%b\install%%~c.swm" ECHO copy /y "c:\sandbox\image\install%%~c.swm" "%%b\install%%~c.swm"
```

Note `for /L` replaced by plain `for`; list is list of suffixes to `install`; when used in the `do` clause, `%%~c` is used in place of `%%c` to remove the quotes.

Comment: This is awesome! I just realized the first file is INSTALL not INSTALL1.  The script picks up 2, 3, and 4 no problem.  I tried to adjust the script but made it worse.  How would I get the script to pick up the INSTALL.swm?